# process exited with code 1 (0x00000001) after Git update 2.36.1 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, bash, git, windows-registry

After I tried to update my Git version to 2.36.1, on my Windows 10 machine I've been getting this error in the Windows terminal: `[process exited with code 1 (0x00000001)]` I have tried to check for registry errors, and I don't have `AutoRun` set in the registry: `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`

I don't have any updates, or drivers that needs to be installed. What could this be?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall git, redownload the recent version and install it?

Comment: yeah I've tried both downloading 2.36 again, and both the previous version 2.35 and the pre-release 2.37 but the same issue

Comment: When exactly do you get this error? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc I got it after I tried to launch the git bash for windows program, and when I tried to use bash in the Windows Terminal

Comment: You mean you are getting this when launching git bash inside Windows Terminal? What happens if you launch git bash stand-alone?

Comment: Same issue both with Windows Terminal and the standalone git bash program

Comment: @Krullmizter: Please check under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` as well.